# Install an NVMe SSD on a Dell Precision 5820 tower

Tags: dell, ssd, nvme

I have a Dell Precision 5820 tower that came with 2 NVMe SSD disks on the FlexBay (the front compartment). I have been talking to Technical Support in my country (Spain) to find out how to install a third NVMe SSD, but they have been so far unable to find a way.

Anyway, I purchased an M.2 NVMe SSD from Dell's web site, assuming that installing it would be piece of cake. I was wrong. It seems that the 5820 only admits 2 NVMe SSDs on the FlexBay. So, is there an alternative way to install it on my 5820, even if it's not on the FlexBay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, yes, it seems that there is indeed an alternative way to install a third NVMe SSD on a Dell Precision 5820. By using a [Dell Ultra-Speed adapter](https://www.dell.com/support/contents/en-us/videos/videoplayer/how-to-install-ultra-speed-card-on-precision-workstation/6079787129001), you can install up to 4 SSDs on an x16 PCI slot.

More information, [here](https://www.dell.com/community/en/conversations/precision-fixed-workstations/install-an-nvme-ssd-on-a-precision-5820-tower/6512c5089d0ee36e6e1cc205).

Answer (score 4):

The 5820 dates from 2017, and Dell were kind of late to the NVMe party (as were most mainstream enterprise servers/appliances). Even on their high-density storage servers NVMe was kind of hit and miss via the flex bays.

I'm not at all surprised if they are only two ports wired for NVMe. Remember that each NVMe port requires 4 PCIe lanes.

Your best bet for additional NVMe storage is going to be an internal NVMe storage card. There are various on the market (the official Dell one is part number 080G5N). You'll just need to double check that you have PCIe bifurcation enabled (so one PCIe slot can be broken into multiple x4 interfaces for each NVMe drive). You might have to shuck the m.2 drive out of the Dell flexbay caddy (or if you can, return it and buy a generic drive).

Comment: Many thanks, most useful. Do you have detailed instruction on how to check for PCI bifurcation and doing the shucking? I mean, how do I install a generic SSD on the 5820? Is there any online resource? Thanks!

Comment: I do not know how to check for bifucation on that model, sorry. I have a 7920 myself which is much newer. As for how to install a generic SSD, you can just grab a regular 2.5" SSD and an appropriate Dell caddy and just slot it in the front. It'll be limited to SATA2 speeds (~700MB/sec). How to install an NVMe SSD, thats a varied question as NVMe comes in several flavours (m.2, u.2, flexbay, PCIe) and depends on what you have.

Comment: Thank you. I'll do some research.

Answer (score 0):

There is a slightly more technical way you can add two more additional NVMe storage devices to the 5820 via the flexbays but it will involve the purchase of additional components.  You'll need:

1 of Dell P/N P31H2 PCIe SAS/NVMe extender with 4 mini-SAS connectors

1 of Dell P/N KWF76 NVMe U.2(U.3) flex bay backplane for Precision 5820 -- also known as Dell kit [750-ABDF]

2 of SFF-8643(mini-SAS) to SFF-8611(occulink) cabling of the desired length to connect from the extender to the additional NVMe backplane needed to support the two extra drives/bottom flexbay

The 5820 motherboard has two mini-SAS connectors that the only/single NVMe U.2(U.3) flexbay backplane that ships with the 5820 connects to. This backplane supports the top two flexbay slots only.  The connectors for it are under the air shroud to the right of the CPU. This permits two NVMe drives to be used, typically of the M.2 form factor supported via the flexbay tray adapters.  You can also use NVMe 2.5 inch U.2(U.3) drives in the more traditional 2.5 drive caddies as well, as the U.2(U.3) drive connector will interface directly with the NVMe U.2(U.3) flexbay backplane.

If you want the bottom two flexbay slots to *also* be NVMe then you first install the PCIe SAS/NVMe extender card in the appropriate PCIe slot, attach two long-ish cables from two ports on the extender card to the additional NVMe backplane on the bottom two flexbay slots, and you're good to go.  The cables supplied with the NVMe backplane are a bit short and don't really reach the extender card as they're desiged to connect to the motherboard from the top flexbay position.  You'll need to remove the existing SATA backplane and cabling from the bottom flexbay to install the new NVMe backplane.  If you plan to run with M.2 form factor drives in the bottom two flexbay slots then you may need to purchase additional flexbay adapters with the M.2 tray support for those as well.

Above all though be careful and know what you're doing with respect to the hardware and any OS installs, etc.  This is a process and may not be worth it considering that you can simply use less accessible M.2 form factor drives directly mounted to a Dell PCIe card.  Also, once you remove the SATA backplane and install the NVMe you can't easily swap back to a SATA drive if something goes awry with an OS install, etc.  If you've already got working OS installs on the top flexbay slots via NVMe and only plan on using the bottom two for NVMe storage then there shouldn't be any major hurdles.